# Copy a range to a new workbook with a condition

Tags: excel, vba

[image: database]

Hi all! 
I have been trying to make vba code for the following purpose: copy a range of a workbook (screenshot above A1:F2) to a new workbook. 
I have managed to achieve this. There is one additional criteria which i would like to add to the vba code. The vba code should only copy those columns where row 2 has a value filled in.
Thus, looking at the example in the screenshot, this would mean that by running the vba code, I would save to a new workbook the ranges A1:A2, C1:C2, E1:E2. 
The new worbook would look like the second screenshot

[image: Screenshot2]

Any help appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very useful way of ignoring blanks - without looping - is to use `SpecialCells`. The code below is probably a little lengthier than needed for your question but it is written so that

1. It can be adapted to other sheets
2. It will copy non-blanks from row 2 whether they are values and/or formulae
3. In absence of seeing your code it copies to a new workbook

**code**

```
Sub CopyEm()
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range
Set ws = Sheets(1)
On Error Resume Next
Set rng1 = ws.Rows(2).SpecialCells(xlConstants)
Set rng2 = ws.Rows(2).SpecialCells(xlFormulas)
If rng1 Is Nothing Then
Set rng3 = rng2
ElseIf rng2 Is Nothing Then
Set rng3 = rng1
Else
Set rng3 = Union(rng1, rng2)
End If
If rng3 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
On Error GoTo 0
Set WB = Workbooks.Add
rng3.Offset(-1, 0).Copy WB.Sheets(1).[a1]
rng3.Copy WB.Sheets(1).[a2]
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, it works! I am now trying to fine-tune the macro. I have posted the request as a new question. Here is the link, if you have any ideas I would really appreciate your help! Thanks            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042340/macro-to-copy-range-to-new-workbook-based-on-condition