# Macro to copy range to new workbook based on condition

Tags: excel, vba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Macro to copy range to new workbook with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034522/macro-to-copy-range-to-new-workbook-with-condition)

I have unsuccesfully been trying to create a macro for the following purpose: copy a range of a workbook  to a new workbook. Looking at the first screenshot in example 1, what I would like to achieve is to copy range R4:AB6 to a new workbook, with an additional criteria. The macro should only copy the rows where the row of the active cell contains values. The second screenshot of example 1 displays what the outcome of the macro would be: a new workbook with the pasted range based on the criteria mentioned. I have added another example to make what I need more clear. In example 2, screenshot 2 displays the starting position where the active cell is R7. The outcome of running the macro would be the final screenshot, where rows 4 and 5 have been copied along with the row of the active cell, and only if that row is not empty.

I would truly appreciate any help, as I am rather new to vba and have been breaking my head on this one for a very long time!

[image: Example1]
[image: Example1]
[image: Example2]
[image: Example2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty crude, but hopefully this helps..

```
Sub bks()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim WB1 As Workbook
Dim WB2 As Workbook
Dim name1 As String
Dim name2 As String
Dim colLet As String

'grab name of current workbook
name1 = ThisWorkbook.Name
Set WB1 = Workbooks(name1)


'create new workbook and set it
Workbooks.Add.Activate
name2 = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Set WB2 = Workbooks(name2)

WB1.Activate

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim mAdjust As Integer
Dim x As Double



'set x equal to number of rows you have
x = 100

Dim colSave() As Double
ReDim colSave(x)

j = 1
k = 1

'the `17` adjust the loop for the R column (17 columns over from 1)
    For i = 1 + 17 To 11 + 17
        For m = 1 To x

'for each row of records, set the first report column to 1 via the array colSave(m)
        If i = 1 + 17 Then
            colSave(m) = 1
        End If
           mAdjust = m + 5
               WB2.Activate
        j = colSave(m)

'convert the column number to column letter
            If i > 26 Then
               colLet = Chr(Int((i - 1) / 26) + 64) & Chr(Int((i - 1) Mod 26) + 65)
            Else
               colLet = Chr(i + 64)
            End If

            WB1.Activate

        'the conditional statements you wanted
                If Cells(mAdjust, i) <> "" Then
                    Range(colLet & "4," & colLet & "5," & colLet & mAdjust).Activate
                        Selection.Copy
                        WB2.Activate
                        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells((m - 1) * 5 + 1, j).Activate
                        ActiveSheet.Paste
                    colSave(m) = colSave(m) + 1
                End If
            Next m
    Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
WB2.Activate

'`j` and `k` allow you to move the paste columns sperately based on your condition.
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, appreciate your time! I get error 400. What could I be missing?

Comment: Where is the error occurring?

Comment: A red cross pops up, right beside it the number 400. Then after I click 'ok' a new workbook opens with nothing pasted. Until now I have pasted the code provided above to the first sheet of the workbook of which the screenshots you have seen above. I have assigned the macro to a shortcut key. I go to cell R6 and run the macro by pressing the assigned shortcut key.

Comment: This macro should work as long as the sheet you're wanting to copy is active when you hit Run.  The code is written for your exact example. You'll have to make some changes to apply it else where.  I believe your error was due to the missing `sheets` declaration in the conditional statements. The code above should be fixed.

Comment: You are a genius, works perfectly now. However my request was slightly different, probably wasn't clear enough. Right now, the macro only works for the first 2 rows (6 and 7). But I would like it to work for any row below all the way to row 10000. So i can go on any cell (R6, R7, R8-R10000) and run the macro and that will do exactly the action that you have programmed: copy row 4 and 5 as well as the row of the active cell based on whether the row with the active cell is empty or not. You are almost there! This is too advanced for me to figure out. Hope you can help! Thanks in advance

Comment: Set `x` to the number of rows you have. Keep in mind, these large loops could take a while even when using VBA.

Comment: something is not working, I will check first thing tomorrow morning and let you know.. thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: As mentioned earlier, the macro is awesome but not 100% as I was imagining it. When I run the macro and the active cell is R6, it does exactly what i am looking for.  It doesn' t work properly however when the active cell is R7, R8, R9, etc.  What I want it to do is: Based on the active cell (which is R6, R7, R8, R9, all the way to R10000), (1) the macro copies the values in the row of the active cell to a new workb(so if i am on R9, it will copy the cells to the right that are not empty) and for those cells, the corresponding two values on row 4 & 5 will be copied as well

Comment: so in total, every time the macro runs, only three rows of data are copied: (1) The row with non-empty values in the row of the active cell, (2&3) Row 4 and Row 5 based on whether the row with active cell at the moment of running the macro is non-empty. If there is anyway you can guide me, it would be hugely helpful. Thanks already for all the code until now!

Comment: Hi Superstatistician, any ideas regarding the above? Thanks

Comment: It works for me. I don't know what your issues are. The code will loop through every row from R6 to R`x`  where x is the number of rows.  This value `x` should be manually set in the code. There many ways you can make this an automated process, but this was a quick and dirty approach.